# cholesky decomposition ScaLapack error

Tags: c++, fortran, blas, scalapack

I'm getting the following error and i'm not sure why.

```
{    1,    1}:  On entry to PDPOTRF parameter number    2 had an illegal value
{    1,    0}:  On entry to PDPOTRF parameter number    2 had an illegal value
{    0,    1}:  On entry to PDPOTRF parameter number    2 had an illegal value
{    0,    0}:  On entry to PDPOTRF parameter number    2 had an illegal value


 info < 0:  If the i-th argument is an array and the j-entry had an illegal value, then INFO = -(i*100+j), if the i-th argument is a scalar and had an illegal value, then INFO = -i.
```

I Know what the error messages means but I followed the dated documentation available on the web as best as possible and tried to piece together a parallel cholesky factorization from working example codes on the web. I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Could some one explain where I went wrong in the code below? Here's an overview of what the code does, I'm testing with 4 processors and divide the 8x8 matrix into 2 x 2 processor block grid
 loads a matrix from file, heres an example 8 x 8 matrixfile ,

```
182   147   140   125   132    76   126   157
147   213   185   150   209   114   166   188
140   185   232   129   194   142   199   205
125   150   129   143   148    81   104   150
132   209   194   148   214   122   172   189
76   114   142    81   122   102   129   117
126   166   199   104   172   129   187   181
157   188   205   150   189   117   181   259
```

I followed examples to distribute the Matrix to 4 separate 4x4 local arrays one on each of the 4 nodes. I then run `descinit_` and call the associated `pdpotrf_` routine which yields the above error. I have no idea where i went wrong and tried to follow documentation as best as I could. A working example of a parallel cholesky decomposition in fortran would also greatly help

**References for function calls**

[pdpotrf_](http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/explore-html/d5/d9e/pdpotrf_8f_source.html)

[descinit_](http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/explore-html/dd/d22/descinit_8f_source.html)

**Run Parameters**

```
code name - Meaning = Value
N - Global Rows = 8
M - Global Cols = 8
Nb - Local Block Rows = 2
Mb - Local Block Cols = 2
nrows - Local Rows = 4
ncols Local Cols= 4
lda - Leading dimension of local array = 4 (i've tried 2,4,8)
ord - Order of Matrix = 4   (i've also tried many different things here as well)
```

I Printed the above parameters on every node and they are the same

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;


/*
  To compile:
  mpic++ test.cpp -o test -L/home/admin/libs -lscalapack -lrefblas -ltmg -lreflapack -lgfortran -Wall -O2
  To run:
  mpirun -np 4 ./test matrixfile 8 8 2 2

*/

extern "C" {
  /* Cblacs declarations */
  void Cblacs_pinfo(int*, int*);
  void Cblacs_get(int, int, int*);
  void Cblacs_gridinit(int*, const char*, int, int);
  void Cblacs_gridinfo(int, int*, int*, int*,int*);
  void Cblacs_pcoord(int, int, int*, int*);
  void Cblacs_gridexit(int);
  void Cblacs_barrier(int, const char*);
  void Cdgerv2d(int, int, int, double*, int, int, int);
  void Cdgesd2d(int, int, int, double*, int, int, int);

  int numroc_(int*, int*, int*, int*, int*);

  void pdpotrf_(char*, int*, double*,
        int*, int*, int*, int*);

  void descinit_( int *, int *, int *, int *, int *, int *, int *,
          int *, int *, int *);

}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  /* MPI */
  int mpirank,nprocs;
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mpirank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocs);
  double MPIelapsed;
  double MPIt2;
  double MPIt1;

  /* Helping vars */
  int iZERO = 0;
  int verbose = 1;
  bool mpiroot = (mpirank == 0);

  if (argc < 6) {
    if (mpiroot)
      cerr << "Usage: matrixTest matrixfile N M Nb Mb"
       << endl
       << " N = Rows , M = Cols , Nb = Row Blocks , Mb = Col Blocks "
       << endl;

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 1;
  }
  /* Scalapack / Blacs Vars */
  int N, M, Nb, Mb;
  int descA[9];
  int info = 0;
  //  int mla = 4;
  int ord = 8;



  double *A_glob = NULL, *A_glob2 = NULL, *A_loc = NULL;

  /* Parse command line arguments */
  if (mpiroot) {
    /* Read command line arguments */
    stringstream stream;
    stream << argv[2] << " " << argv[3] << " " << argv[4] << " " << argv[5];
    stream >> N >> M >> Nb >> Mb;


    /* Reserve space and read matrix (with transposition!) */
    A_glob  = new double[N*M];
    A_glob2 = new double[N*M];
    string fname(argv[1]);
    ifstream file(fname.c_str());
    for (int r = 0; r < N; ++r) {
      for (int c = 0; c < M; ++c) {
    file >> *(A_glob + N*c + r);
      }
    }

    /* Print matrix */

      if(verbose == 1) {
    cout << "Matrix A:\n";
    for (int r = 0; r < N; ++r) {
      for (int c = 0; c < M; ++c) {
        cout << setw(3) << *(A_glob + N*c + r) << " ";
      }
      cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << endl;
      }


  }

  /* Begin Cblas context */
  int ctxt, myid, myrow, mycol, numproc;
  //<TODO> make dynamic
  int procrows = 2, proccols = 2;
  Cblacs_pinfo(&myid, &numproc);
  Cblacs_get(0, 0, &ctxt);
  Cblacs_gridinit(&ctxt, "Row-major", procrows, proccols);
  Cblacs_gridinfo( ctxt, &procrows, &proccols, &myrow, &mycol );
  /* process coordinates for the process grid */
  // Cblacs_pcoord(ctxt, myid, &myrow, &mycol);


  /* Broadcast of the matrix dimensions */
  int dimensions[4];
  if (mpiroot) {
    dimensions[0] = N;//Global Rows
    dimensions[1] = M;//Global Cols
    dimensions[2] = Nb;//Local Rows
    dimensions[3] = Mb;//Local Cols
  }
  MPI_Bcast(dimensions, 4, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  MPI_Bcast(&ord, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  N = dimensions[0];
  M = dimensions[1];
  Nb = dimensions[2];
  Mb = dimensions[3];

  int nrows = numroc_(&N, &Nb, &myrow, &iZERO, &procrows);
  int ncols = numroc_(&M, &Mb, &mycol, &iZERO, &proccols);

  int lda = max(1,nrows);

  MPI_Bcast(&lda, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  /* Print grid pattern */
  if (myid == 0)
    cout << "Processes grid pattern:" << endl;
  for (int r = 0; r < procrows; ++r) {
    for (int c = 0; c < proccols; ++c) {
      Cblacs_barrier(ctxt, "All");
      if (myrow == r && mycol == c) {
    cout << myid << " " << flush;
      }
    }
    Cblacs_barrier(ctxt, "All");
    if (myid == 0)
      cout << endl;
  }

  if(myid == 0){
    cout <<"Run Parameters"<<endl;
    cout <<"Global Rows = " << M <<endl;
    cout <<"Global Cols = " << N <<endl;
    cout <<"Local Block Rows = " << Mb <<endl;
    cout <<"Local Block Cols = " << Nb <<endl;
    cout << "nrows = "<<nrows<<endl;
    cout << "ncols = "<<ncols<<endl;
    cout << "lda = "<<lda<<endl;
    cout <<"Order = "<<ord<<endl;
  }


  for (int id = 0; id < numproc; ++id) {
    Cblacs_barrier(ctxt, "All");
  }
  A_loc = new double[nrows*ncols];
  for (int i = 0; i < nrows*ncols; ++i) *(A_loc+i)=0.;

  /* Scatter matrix */
  int sendr = 0, sendc = 0, recvr = 0, recvc = 0;
  for (int r = 0; r < N; r += Nb, sendr=(sendr+1)%procrows) {
    sendc = 0;
    int nr = Nb;
    if (N-r < Nb)
      nr = N-r;

    for (int c = 0; c < M; c += Mb, sendc=(sendc+1)%proccols) {
      int nc = Mb;
      if (M-c < Mb)
    nc = M-c;

      if (mpiroot) {
    Cdgesd2d(ctxt, nr, nc, A_glob+N*c+r, N, sendr, sendc);
      }

      if (myrow == sendr && mycol == sendc) {
    Cdgerv2d(ctxt, nr, nc, A_loc+nrows*recvc+recvr, nrows, 0, 0);
    recvc = (recvc+nc)%ncols;
      }

    }

    if (myrow == sendr)
      recvr = (recvr+nr)%nrows;
  }

  /* Print local matrices */
  if(verbose == 1) {
  for (int id = 0; id < numproc; ++id) {
    if (id == myid) {
    cout << "A_loc on node " << myid << endl;
    for (int r = 0; r < nrows; ++r) {
      for (int c = 0; c < ncols; ++c)
        cout << setw(3) << *(A_loc+nrows*c+r) << " ";
      cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
      }
      Cblacs_barrier(ctxt, "All");
    }
  }

  for (int id = 0; id < numproc; ++id) {
    Cblacs_barrier(ctxt, "All");
  }

  /* DescInit */
  info=0;
  descinit_(descA, &N, &M, &Nb, &Mb,&iZERO,&iZERO,&ctxt, &lda, &info);

  if(mpiroot){
    if(verbose == 1){
      if (info == 0){
    cout<<"Description init sucesss!"<<endl;
      }
      if(info < 0){
    cout <<"Error Info < 0: if INFO = -i, the i-th argument had an illegal value"<< endl
         <<"Info = " << info<<endl;
      }
    }
    // Cblacs_barrier(ctxt, "All");
  }

  //psgesv_(n, 1, al, 1,1,idescal, ipiv, b, 1,1,idescb,  info) */
  //    psgesv_(&n, &one, al, &one,&one,idescal, ipiv, b, &one,&one,idescb,  &info);
  //pXelset http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/tools/pdelset.f


  /* CHOLESKY HERE */
  info = 0;
  MPIt1=MPI_Wtime();

  pdpotrf_("L",&ord,A_loc,&Nb,&Mb,descA,&info);

  for (int id = 0; id < numproc; ++id) {
    Cblacs_barrier(ctxt, "All");
  }

  MPIt2 = MPI_Wtime();
  MPIelapsed=MPIt2-MPIt1;
  if(mpiroot){
    std::cout<<"Cholesky MPI Run Time" << MPIelapsed<<std::endl;

    if(info == 0){
      std::cout<<"SUCCESS"<<std::endl;
    }
    if(info < 0){

      cout << "info < 0:  If the i-th argument is an array and the j-entry had an illegal value, then INFO = -(i*100+j), if the i-th argument is a scalar and had an illegal value, then INFO = -i. " << endl;
      cout<<"info = " << info << endl;
    }
    if(info > 0){
      std::cout<<"matrix is not positve definte"<<std::endl;
    }
  }

  //sanity check set global matrix to zero before it's recieved by nodes
  if(mpiroot){
    for (int r = 0; r < N; ++r) {
      for (int c = 0; c < M; ++c) {
    A_glob2[c *N + r]  = 0; 
      }
    }
  }

  /* Gather matrix */
  sendr = 0;
  for (int r = 0; r < N; r += Nb, sendr=(sendr+1)%procrows) {
    sendc = 0;
    // Number of rows to be sent
    // Is this the last row block?
    int nr = Nb;
    if (N-r < Nb)
      nr = N-r;

    for (int c = 0; c < M; c += Mb, sendc=(sendc+1)%proccols) {
      // Number of cols to be sent
      // Is this the last col block?
      int nc = Mb;
      if (M-c < Mb)
    nc = M-c;

      if (myrow == sendr && mycol == sendc) {
    // Send a nr-by-nc submatrix to process (sendr, sendc)
    Cdgesd2d(ctxt, nr, nc, A_loc+nrows*recvc+recvr, nrows, 0, 0);
    recvc = (recvc+nc)%ncols;
      }

      if (mpiroot) {
    // Receive the same data
    // The leading dimension of the local matrix is nrows!
    Cdgerv2d(ctxt, nr, nc, A_glob2+N*c+r, N, sendr, sendc);
      }
    }
    if (myrow == sendr)
      recvr = (recvr+nr)%nrows;
  }
  /* Print test matrix */
  if (mpiroot) {
    if(verbose == 1){
      cout << "Matrix A test:\n";
      for (int r = 0; r < N; ++r) {
    for (int c = 0; c < M; ++c) {
      cout << setw(3) << *(A_glob2+N*c+r) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
      }
    }
  }

  /* Release resources */
  delete[] A_glob;
  delete[] A_glob2;
  delete[] A_loc;
  Cblacs_gridexit(ctxt);
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: That is an awful lot of code to look at. Couldn't you at least dump out the arguments you are passing to each `PDPOTRF` call and sanity check them to see whether something is obviously wrong?

Comment: @talonmies That is why i gave a +500 bounty for help. I've tried just about everything, including printing out every parameter in the `descinit_` and the 'pdpotrf_` call on every node. I can write them all up above if that would help?

Comment: It would help. Right now it is basically impossible to help you without have a working blacs and scalapack installation, creating the input file and building and running your code. Any extra information you can provide will help make the problem solving  process easier.

Comment: @talonmies thank you for the suggestion i've updating the above with the requested info

Comment: are you sure A_loc really contains valid data on each node? It would seem to me to be the vulnerable spot here. Are you sure you for example that you understood the "Lower" and "Upper" triangles the same way the code is expecting them?

Comment: should "ord" be a pointer or a value?

Comment: @pyCthon Does it work if you use only one node that runs the full 8x8 block instead of splitting up, i.e. `mpirun -np 1 ./test matrix 8 8 8 8`?

Comment: @us2012 I get the same error and I changed all the parameters according to work with blacs

Comment: @MarkusMikkolainen I printed out A_loc on every node and it prints correctly, ord is a value, so are you suggesting that the user is forced to set the upper or lower triangular part to zeros?

Comment: @MarkusMikkolainen the documentation simply states that either the lower or upper part of the matrix is simply not referenced, for an NxN symmetric positive definite matrix

Comment: @pyCthon It seems I have found and solved the problem - see my answer below.

Comment: Relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30937544/confused-with-pdpotrf-arguments

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right - I solved this. Here's what you have to do (I checked the result of the modified MPI program against a Cholesky decomp of your matrix in Octave -- it works.).

I found the following LAPACK reference by IBM to be more helpful than the one in your link:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/clresctr/vxrx/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.cluster.pessl.v4r2.pssl100.doc%2Fam6gr_lpotrf.htm

`PDPOTRF( UPLO, N, A, IA, JA, DESCA, INFO )`

You are passing `Mb` and `Nb` as `IA` and `JA`. However, those parameters are meant to provide the starting row and column of your global matrix inside a larger matrix. They are only relevant if you have a big matrix and only want the Cholesky decomp of a submatrix. In your case, `IA` and `JA` both have to be `1`!

So all you need to do is:

```
int IA = 1;
int JA = 1;
pdpotrf_("L",&ord,A_loc,&IA,&JA,descA,&info);
```

You may also want to change your hardcoded `int ord = 8;` so that it depends on the value read from the command line, otherwise you'll run into problems later.

Output of your program modified as described above:

```
Cholesky MPI Run Time0.000659943
SUCCESS
Matrix A test:
13.4907 147 140 125 132  76 126 157 
10.8964 9.70923 185 150 209 114 166 188 
10.3775 7.4077 8.33269 129 194 142 199 205 
9.26562 5.0507 -0.548194 5.59806 148  81 104 150 
9.78449 10.5451 1.72175 0.897537 1.81524 122 172 189 
5.63349 5.41911 5.20784 0.765767 0.0442447 3.63139 129 117 
9.33974 6.61543 6.36911 -2.22569 1.03941 2.48498 1.79738 181 
11.6376 6.30249 4.50561 2.28799 -0.627688 -2.17633 7.27182 0.547228
```

Octave output for comparison:

```
octave:1> A=dlmread("matrixfile4")
A =

   182   147   140   125   132    76   126   157
   147   213   185   150   209   114   166   188
   140   185   232   129   194   142   199   205
   125   150   129   143   148    81   104   150
   132   209   194   148   214   122   172   189
    76   114   142    81   122   102   129   117
   126   166   199   104   172   129   187   181
   157   188   205   150   189   117   181   259

octave:2> C=chol(A)
C =

   13.49074   10.89636   10.37749    9.26562    9.78449    5.63349    9.33974   11.63761
    0.00000    9.70923    7.40770    5.05070   10.54508    5.41911    6.61543    6.30249
    0.00000    0.00000    8.33269   -0.54819    1.72175    5.20784    6.36911    4.50561
    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    5.59806    0.89754    0.76577   -2.22569    2.28799
    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.81524    0.04424    1.03941   -0.62769
    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    3.63139    2.48498   -2.17633
    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    1.79738    7.27182
    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000    0.54723
```

(My earlier comment -now deleted- about matrices being wrongly copied to the nodes does not apply, the rest of your program seems fine to me.)

Comment: Nice answer +1. However, I still can't get how the arguments work, so I made a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30937544/confused-with-pdpotrf-arguments