# Confused with pdpotrf arguments

Tags: c++, mpi, linear-algebra, intel-mkl, scalapack

I want to do a Cholesky factorization in a distributed environment. For that purpose, I use [pdpotrf()](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/521465). However, I am struggling understanding the parameters needed by the function and they provide no C example on how to use it (and an example would be really great to have).

Assume I have a NxX matrix I want to factorize. Then, what values should the parameters have? `uplo`, `a` and `info` are well defined in my mind. How about the rest?

`n` should be equal to N I would say. However, `desca`, `ia` and `ja` are the ones that confuse me. Moreover, `desca` is global and local, something that I can't understand. Can someone explain? Maybe with an approach-example (not necessarily code, since I want to understand, not just copy paste).

<sub>I do *not* know any Fortran.</sub>

Comment: You first need to study how this package distributes matrices, after that you will know what do the arguments mean. You do not need Fortran. You do need to read the ScaLAPACK manual.

Comment: If I could find that, it would be great! Can't we say how the distribution happens from the parameters @VladimirF?

Comment: You must rtfm http://netlib.org/scalapack/slug/node35.html

Comment: @VladimirF believe it or not, yesterday night (when I was out), I thought I should google "distribute matrix in ScaLAPACK". And yes, should RTFM! Will investigate the link you gave. You may also wish to make an answer with that.

Comment: @VladimirF I did read it, but still I can't figure it out. I will continue searching and report back if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14203864/2411320), we have:

> `IA` and `JA`: those parameters are meant to provide the starting row and column of your global matrix inside a larger matrix. They are only relevant if you have a big matrix and only want the Cholesky decomp of a submatrix. In your case, `IA` and `JA` both have to be `1`!

Again, from this answer, there exists a [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNR5K_4.2.0/com.ibm.cluster.pessl.v4r2.pssl100.doc/am6gr_lpotrf.htm), that describes `desca`:

[image]