# Cholesky with ScaLAPACK

Tags: c++, distributed-computing, blas, intel-mkl, scalapack

I am trying to do a Cholesky decomposition via [pdpotrf()](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/521465) of MKL-Intel's library, which uses ScaLAPACK. I am reading the whole matrix in the master node and then distribute it like in this [example](https://andyspiros.wordpress.com/2011/07/08/an-example-of-blacs-with-c/). Everything works fine when the dimension of the SPD matrix is even. However, when it's odd, `pdpotrf()` thinks that the matrix is not positive definite.

Could it be because the submatrices are not SPD? I am working with this matrix: [image]

and the submatrices are (with 4 processes and blocks of size 2x2):

```
A_loc on node 0
  4   1   2
  1 0.5   0
  2   0  16

nrows = 3, ncols = 2
A_loc on node 1
  2 0.5
  0   0
  0   0

nrows = 2, ncols = 3
A_loc on node 2
  2   0   0
0.5   0   0

nrows = 2, ncols = 2
A_loc on node 3
  3   0
  0 0.625
```

Here, every submatrix is not SPD, however, the overall matrix is SPD (have checked with running with 1 process). What should I do? Or there is nothing I can do and `pdpotrf()` does not work with matrices of odd size?

---

Here is how  I call the routine:

```
int iZERO = 0;
int descA[9];
// N, M dimensions of matrix. lda = N
// Nb, Mb dimensions of block
descinit_(descA, &N, &M, &Nb, &Mb, &iZERO, &iZERO, &ctxt, &lda, &info);
...
pdpotrf((char*)"L", &ord, A_loc, &IA, &JA, descA, &info);
```

I also tried this:

```
// nrows/ncols is the number of rows/columns a submatrix has
descinit_(descA, &N, &M, &nrows, &ncols, &iZERO, &iZERO, &ctxt, &lda, &info);
```

but I get an error:

> {    0,    0}:  On entry to {    0,    1}:  On entry to  PDPOTR{    1,
>   0}:  On entry to  PDPOTRF parameter number  605 had an illegal value {
>   1,    1}:  On entry to  PDPOTRF parameter number  605 had an illegal
>   value  F parameter number  605 had an illegal value
>
> PDPOTRF parameter number  605 had an illegal value  info < 0:  If the
>   i-th argument is an array and the j-entry had an illegal value, then
>   INFO = -(i*100+j), if the i-th argument is a scalar and had an illegal
>   value, then INFO = -i.  info = -605

From my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31137250/2411320), you can see what the arguments of the function mean.

---

The code is based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147705/cholesky-decomposition-scalapack-error?rq=1). Output:

```
gsamaras@pythagoras:~/konstantis/check_examples$ ../../mpich-install/bin/mpic++ -o test minor.cpp -I../../intel/mkl/include ../../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_scalapack_lp64.a       -Wl,--start-group       ../../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.a ../../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a  ../../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.a    -Wl,--end-group ../../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64.a -lpthread       -lm     -ldl
gsamaras@pythagoras:~/konstantis/check_examples$ mpiexec -n 4 ./test
Processes grid pattern:
0 1
2 3
nrows = 3, ncols = 3
A_loc on node 0
  4   1   2
  1 0.5   0
  2   0  16

nrows = 3, ncols = 2
A_loc on node 1
  2 0.5
  0   0
  0   0

nrows = 2, ncols = 3
A_loc on node 2
  2   0   0
0.5   0   0

nrows = 2, ncols = 2
A_loc on node 3
  3   0
  0 0.625

Description init sucesss!
matrix is not positive definte
Matrix A result:
  2   1   2 0.5   2
0.5 0.5   0   0   0
  1   0   1   0 -0.25
0.25  -1 -0.5 0.625   0
  1  -1  -2 -0.5  14
```

Comment: You might try the LAPACK version (dpotrf)...

Comment: That's not distributed @Jeff. I have checked that with `dpotrf()` as well and it works. However, I am interested only in distributed solutions.

Comment: I am aware of that. The point was to get debugging insight. It seems you've done that.

Comment: You could also try Elemental, which has a more friendly API, performs the same or better for Cholesky, and supports more than just dense matrices.

Comment: Oh OK @Jeff, yes I had, should have mentioned, sorry, will edit. I know Elemental, and Jack Poulson who is the project leader is very friendly and good. However, I had to use ScaLAPACK for various reasons. So, now I have to see what's going on with `pdpotrf()`. Do you think that it can not handle odd dimensions?

Comment: I'm sure it can handle odd dimensions. My guess is that there is an error in your input arguments. Best thing to do is include a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @Jeff I updated the question. Hope the downvoter will see that too! EDIT: Guess (s)he did not!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue may come from :

```
MPI_Bcast(&lda, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Before this line, `lda` is different on each process if the dimension of the matrix is odd. Two processes handle 2 rows and two processes handle 3 rows. But after the `MPI_Bcast()`, `lda` is the same everywhere (3).

The problem is that the argument `lda` of the subroutine [`DESCINIT`](http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/explore-html/dd/d22/descinit_8f_source.html) must be the leading dimension of the local array, that is either 2 or 3.

By commenting `MPI_Bcast()`, i got:

```
Description init sucesss!
SUCCESS
Matrix A result:
2   1   2 0.5   2 
0.5 0.5   0   0   0 
1  -1   1   0   0 
0.25 -0.25 -0.5 0.5   0 
1  -1  -2  -3   1
```

At last, it would explain that the program works well for even dimensions and fails for odd dimensions !

Comment: Oh, I thought of the global matrix, good job Francis. Nice top answer btw. Dacor :P There is also this link: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/561007