# error in OpenMP program execution

Tags: openmp

I am trying to sum all the elements of an array which is initialized in the same code. As every element is independent from each other, I tried to perform the sum in parallel. My code is shown below:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
  cout.precision(20);
  double sumre=0.,Mre[11];
  int n=11;
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
   Mre[i]=2.*exp(-10*M_PI*i/(1.*n));

  #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sumre)
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
   sumre+=Mre[i];
  }
  cout<<sumre<<"\n";
}
```

which I compile and run with:

```
g++ -O3 -o sum sumparallel.cpp -fopenmp
./sum
```

respectively. My problem is that the output differs every time I run it. Sometimes it gives

2.1220129388411006488

or

2.1220129388411002047
Does anyone have an idea what is happening here?

Comment: `double` only have 15–17 significant decimal digits precision.

Comment: My main concern is that I am very interested in getting good precision, so I do not know how I could manage this by using OpenMP.

Comment: Also relevant and covered in several SO Qs and As, is the non-associativity of f-p arithmetic and the non-determinism of parallel f-p arithmetic.  One of my own modest contributions to the sum of knowledge -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074644/fix-arithmetic-error-in-distributed-version/ -- and there are others.

Answer (score 2):

Some of these comments hint at the problem here, but there could be two distinct issues

**Double precision numbers do not have 20 decimal precision**

If you want to print the maximum precision of `sumre`, use something like this

```
#include <float.h>
int maint(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  ...

  printf("%.*g", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, number);

  return 0;
}
```

**Floating point arithmetic is non-commutative**

The effect of this property is roundoff error. In fact, the function that you have defined, a gaussian, is especially prone to roundoff for summation. Considering that workload distribution of OpenMP `parallel for` is undefined, you may receive different answers when you run it. To get around this you may use the [kahan summation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm).  An implementation with OpenMP would look something like this:

```
  ...
  double sum = 0.0, c = 0.0; 

  #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum, +:c) 
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++) 
  { 
    double y = Mre[i] - c; 
    double t = sum + y; 
    c = (t - sum) - y; 
    sum = t; 
  } 

  sum = sum - c;  
  ...
```